# dplyr Filter Multiple numbers over multiple columns simultaneously

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set like this:

```
PatientNum<- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Age<- c(10, 21, 51, 42, 35) 
SurgicalProcedureNumber <- c(21356, 21424, 221356, 12345, 54321) 
OtherSurgicalProcedureNumber   <- c(54321, 21356, 12345, 12345, 21424) 
BloodLoss<-c(5,4,5,10,5)
YetAnotherSurgicalProcedureNumber<-c(11111,22222,33333,21356,555555)

dataset <- data.frame(PatientNum, Age, SurgicalProcedureNumber, OtherSurgicalProcedureNumber, BloodLoss,YetAnotherSurgicalProcedureNumber)
```

I want to know when the patients underwent certain surgeries:

```
NumbersIcareAbout<- c(21356,21424)
```

I know to find them in one column I could do:

```
dataset%>%filter(SurgicalProcedureNumber%in%NumbersIcareAbout)
```

And that would return patient 1 and 2 because it has those codes... but I want it to return the row anytime those numbers shows up in SurgicalProcedureNumber,OtherSurgicalProcedureNumber, or YetAnotherSurgicalProcedureNumber

No idea how and couldn't find it on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the OR operator `|` like this:

```
dataset %>%
  filter(SurgicalProcedureNumber %in% NumbersIcareAbout | 
           OtherSurgicalProcedureNumber %in% NumbersIcareAbout | 
           YetAnotherSurgicalProcedureNumber %in% NumbersIcareAbout)

#   PatientNum Age SurgicalProcedureNumber OtherSurgicalProcedureNumber BloodLoss YetAnotherSurgicalProcedureNumber
# 1          1  10                   21356                        54321         5                             11111
# 2          2  21                   21424                        21356         4                             22222
# 3          4  42                   12345                        12345        10                             21356
# 4          5  35                   54321                        21424         5                            555555
```

---

I'm sure there's a more elegant way, but this filters to those with matches in 2 or more columns (I think):

```
dataset %>%
  filter((SurgicalProcedureNumber %in% NumbersIcareAbout + 
          OtherSurgicalProcedureNumber %in% NumbersIcareAbout + 
          YetAnotherSurgicalProcedureNumber %in% NumbersIcareAbout) >= 2)

#   PatientNum Age SurgicalProcedureNumber OtherSurgicalProcedureNumber BloodLoss YetAnotherSurgicalProcedureNumber
# 1          2  21                   21424                        21356         4                             22222
```

It works by summing together the logical vectors that result from your comparisons using `%in%`. It relies on the fact that `TRUE + TRUE` gives `2`. So, if a row has a value of 2 or greater then it has multiple matches.

Comment: Thank you, thats perfect.

And at first I was thinking just use the AND operator to catch matches in two or more columns, but that actually works better  (because in reality I have like twenty columns I'm filtering, and its doubtful there will be relevant numbers in all twenty, but your solution would catch those where it matches in a few columns.

Answer (score 6):

In `dplyr` version 1.0.4, we can use `filter` with `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>%
      filter(if_any(ends_with("ProcedureNumber"), ~ . %in% NumbersIcareAbout))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `dplyr::filter_at` as filter condition is expected to be applied to columns ending with `ProcedureNumber`.

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>% filter_at(vars(ends_with("ProcedureNumber")), 
                                 any_vars(. %in% NumbersIcareAbout))
```

**Result**

```
#   PatientNum Age SurgicalProcedureNumber OtherSurgicalProcedureNumber BloodLoss YetAnotherSurgicalProcedureNumber
# 1          1  10                   21356                        54321         5                             11111
# 2          2  21                   21424                        21356         4                             22222
# 3          4  42                   12345                        12345        10                             21356
# 4          5  35                   54321                        21424         5                            555555
```

Comment: Oooh that might really help as well.  I have like 20 columns that end with CPT (its like my procedure number above) so that might be a better way of filtering all of them rather than typing out each column name.

Comment: @JoeCrozier Absolutely correct. You can even think of having `&` condition with it.